# string comparison in if loop doesnt work

Tags: java, jsp

I am having an if loop which is highlighted below. The problem is that even though "secondentry" contains "literature", then also the if loop is entered which is not correct. Am i missing anything?

here is my code:-

```
  if (strLine.contains(wID))
  {
      String splitarray[] = strLine.split("\t");
String firstentry = splitarray[0];
String secondentry = splitarray[1];

     **if(secondentry!="literature")**
                 {
          out.println ("Domain is: "+secondentry+"\n\n"+"<br/><br/>"); 
                  %>
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="r<%=k%>" VALUE="<%=wordID%>">
        <%
        out.println("Gloss= "+word1.getSynset().getGloss()+"<br/><br/>");
        %>
        <%
     }
  }
```

Comment: Again... `secondentry.equals("literature")`

Comment: TOP 1 pitfall in Java:  comparing String object references instead of String's characters ...

Comment: try this : if(secondentry.equal("literature"))

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method equals to compare String

```
!secondentry.equals("literature")
```

Answer (score 0):

(secondentry!="literature")

You checking here if pointer of secondentry equals pointer of literature.
You should use equals function of strings.
For example: secondentry.equals(stringTocheckWith).

Comment: yes tht worked. thank you. i am familiar with asp.net so I did not figure this out.  can you please give some reference to these conccepts

Answer (score 0):

!secondentry.equals("literature")       ;p

Comment: thanks that worked, could you cite any reference for this